# Помогите с регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть поток данных и регулярка с помощью которой я осуществляю поиск в данном потоке

```
$pattern = "/(".$result['name'].").\[(\d{1,2})\].{1,3}(\d{1,2})?.{1,3}?([PVFERUL]+)/";

$result = preg_match_all($pattern,$data,$found,PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

В `$result['name']` подставляется название из базы.Например :Зачаровать Кольцо

Проблема вот в чем,в ячейках [4] в массивах отображается не полное название,почему так подскажите пожалуйста

```
 [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => Зачаровать Кольцо [12] (x2)  VP
            [1] => Зачаровать Кольцо
            [2] => 12
            [3] => 2
            [4] => VP
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => Зачаровать Кольцо [12]  VP
            [1] => Зачаровать Кольцо
            [2] => 12
            [3] => 
            [4] => P
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => Зачаровать Кольцо [11]  VF
            [1] => Зачаровать Кольцо
            [2] => 11
            [3] => 
            [4] => F
        )
```

Comment: Похоже, что вот эта часть выражения

    .{1,3}?

сопоставляется с максимальным (от 1 до 3-х) возможным количеством любых символов, но так, чтобы вот эта

    ([PVFERUL]+)

все же сработала.

--

Вообще, Вы бы точные образцы входных текстов привели, а то с пробелами не очень ясно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо разобрался.

Было - `{1,3}(\d{1,2})`?
Исправил - `{1,3}?(\d{1,2})`?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, по хорошему, я бы переписал вашу регулярку в более понятную, так как конструкции .{1,3} и .{1,3}? не самые удачные, они могут поглощать в себя символы, которые вы бы хотели изъять. Потому регулярку надо писать из потребностей поиска.

```
"/(".$result['name'].")\s*\[(\d{1,2})\]\s*(\(\w+(\d+)\))?\s*([PVFERUL]+)/"
```

[image: regexp]

В поиске будет на одну группу больше, но в данном случае не возникнет проблем с поглощением лишних символов конструкцией .{1,3}

Comment: Спасибо большое,я просто только начал вникать в регулярки,поэтому для начала пишу как получается а не как разумнее будет))) Сейчас буду вникать в ваш вариант!

Comment: +еще такой вопрос,подскажите пожалуйста,что у вас за редактор такой для проверки регулярок!

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/ - советую начать пользоваться им как можно скорее, это очень мощная IDE c почти бесконечными возможностями. Альтернативы ей конечно есть, но для PHP наверное самый лучший вариант это она.

Comment: http://regex101.com/ - сервис для разбора регулярок.
http://habrahabr.ru/post/192920/ - обзорная статья.

UPD: Исправленная регулярка: "/(".$result['name'].")\s\*\[(\d+)\]\s\*(\(\w+(\d+)\))?\s\*([PVFERUL]+)/"

Вместо \d{1,2} в данном случае лучше использовать \d+